# How does locationManager get coordinates?

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I can't understand how CLLocationManager get my current location coordinates ? if I don't call [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] and don't set parameters in locationManager.location.coordinate.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView.delegate = self;

[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

[locationManager setDelegate:self];

[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}


-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *) mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationManager.location.coordinate, 1000, 1000);

[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. I suggest you edit it to include a clearly stated question that will produce a concise answer.

Comment: It may be a cached value from a previous execution.  Look at locationManager.location.timestamp.  It might even be caused by setting the map view's showsUserLocation to YES.  Also, if you're using the map view to show user location, you don't need CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's a cached value after MapView requested current location update because of the following line:
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];